# PHP - Bot Telegram - Post message in Channel and then post comment/reply to the linked Discussion group

Tags: php, api, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

**Summary**

I want to achieve this scenario:

1. My Telegram bot (written in PHP, using Telegram Bot API) posts **a message in a Channel**.
2. **the message** is being autoposted at linked **Discussion group**
3. **THE TASK:** I want my bot to auto post first comment (reply) to the message in the thread at Discussion group (so in the Channel we can see that the message has comments).

**My bot is not watching comments and posts**, just post messages at the specific time.